# Ionic and Angular: "::ng-deep" works with CSS, but not with preprocessors (SASS/SCSS)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3, angular-material

I'm facing with a little strange issue: `::ng-deep` works fine with regular CSS, but when I tried to switch to SASS, I found, that all styles, which declared with `::ng-deep` (I need to use `::ng-deep` to change some Angular Material styles), doesn't apply. But all other styles works fine.

Need to say, that I use not pure Angular:

```
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"@angular/*": "5.0.3",
"@ionic-native/*": "4.5.3",
...
```

Here are my `defaults` in **.angular-cli.json**:

```
{
  ...
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss", // also tried with "sass"
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

And here is my **sass.config.js** (not sure which lines you need, so I'll post the full file):

```
module.exports = {
  outputFilename: process.env.IONIC_OUTPUT_CSS_FILE_NAME,
  sourceMap: false,
  outputStyle: 'expanded',
  autoprefixer: {
    browsers: [
      'last 2 versions',
      'iOS >= 8',
      'Android >= 4.4',
      'Explorer >= 11',
      'ExplorerMobile >= 11'
    ],
    cascade: false
  },
  includePaths: [
    'node_modules/ionic-angular/themes',
    'node_modules/ionicons/dist/scss',
    'node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts',
    'node_modules/font-awesome/scss'
  ],
  includeFiles: [
    /\.(s(c|a)ss)$/i
  ],
  excludeFiles: [
    /*  /\.(wp).(scss)$/i  */
  ],
  variableSassFiles: [
    '{{SRC}}/theme/variables.scss'
  ],
  directoryMaps: {
    '{{TMP}}': '{{SRC}}'
  },
  excludeModules: [
    '@angular',
    'commonjs-proxy',
    'core-js',
    'ionic-native',
    'rxjs',
    'zone.js'
  ]
};
```

Did I miss something while migrating? And if you need more info - just ask, I'll update the question.

**component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-pincode-enter',
  templateUrl: './pincode-enter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['/pincode-enter.component.scss'], // this path is correct, styles without "::ng-deep" works fine
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // tried all 3 properties
})
```

`pincode-enter.component.scss` is at the same folder.
**pincode-enter.component.scss:**

```
/* Tried both with "::ng-deep" and without */
:host .mat-button-wrapper {
  line-height: 72px;
  background-color: red !important;
  color: yellow !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep .mat-button-wrapper {
  line-height: 72px;
  background-color: red !important;
  color: yellow !important;
}
```

And above styles are not applied:

[image]

I also tried to move this styles to global stylesheet, but with no luck again.

Comment: Is it showing errors when compiling or silently failing?

Comment: No errors, all styles with `:host ::ng-deep ...` (i'm on scss now) doesn't apply (and other variations too).

Comment: Post your `component.ts`, `style.scss`, only relevant parts will do. I have had times when I changed `css` to `sass` but forgot to update in `component.ts` file :)

Comment: @sabithpocker, I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you escaping them properly?

<kbd>style.sass</kbd>

```
\:host /deep/ .changed
    color: red
```

Also, [`/deep/` is deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep), so better don't use that.

An alternate would be to try [switching off view-encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) in your component, and scoping the styles with `\:host` so that styles don't leak *out*.

<kbd>component.ts</kbd>

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

Also check these [recommendations from Material Team](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles#styling-other-components)

This [Blog post](https://blog.angular.io/the-state-of-css-in-angular-4a52d4bd2700) is also informative, it suggests to use `:ng-deep` :)

> We understand that there are legitimate use cases for component-scoped
>   CSS, where your styles pierce into child components. Here are three
>   ways you can achieve this:
>
> 1. Use Custom Properties (AKA CSS Variables) — While there isn’t complete browser support for Custom Properties yet, browser
>      implementation of these capabilities will give developers the best
>      combination of isolation and flexibility. Custom Properties, in
>      effect, allow component authors to define an API surface for the
>      styles of their components; they let developers decide what should be
>      styled externally and what needs to stay consistent.
> 2. Use globally-scoped styles sheets and emulated encapsulation — Using traditional CSS you can refer to components by
>      name as part of CSS selectors which will cause styles will be applied
>      as they always have, including piercing down to child components,
>      assuming that you use our emulated (default) view encapsulation on
>      your components.
> 3. Use ::ng-deep — If you need this today, use ::ng-deep. This shouldn’t conflict with any 3rd party tools or new browser
>      development. We are committed to keeping ::ng-deep around until a
>      standards-based approach has achieved industry-wide support.

Comment: I suggest that the issue is somewhere in integration Ionic and Angular, because it worked in pure Angular projects.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried this trick with encapsulation before asking the question, but with no luck too. I understand that it **must** work, but for some reason it's not.

Comment: Can you post a sample CSS that doesn't work along with a structure of your DOM+Shadow-DOM

Comment: Sure, give me a minute

Comment: It's really hard to understand what's going on, but I'm very thankful for you help. Anyway, upvote.

Comment: I didn't solve it, because really have no idea why it doesn't work. I just switched back to CSS and was sad

Answer (score 0):

Since **::ng-deep**, **/deep/** and **>>>** are to be deprecated (or already have), have you tried **:host** instead?

Comment: `/deep/` and `>>>` are deprecated, yes, but not sure that `::ng-deep` is deprecated too. I'll try it with `:host` in few minutes.

Comment: /deep/ and >>> are aliases for ::ng-deep so if they are, it will be too